# jQuery live not updating button value on success

Tags: jquery, ajax

okay, here's the situation:

```
<div>
<a href=".." id=".."></a> //similarly multiple links
</div>
```

when user clicks on any link, it's `id` is passed as a `GET` variable by an AJAX request. Upon success, another `<div>` gets filled up with a list of buttons that have some values written on them. When the user clicks on the buttons, he can change the value written on the button by typing the new value in the alert box. This too is being done by an AJAX request. Upon success however, the values are updated in the database but the changed value is not written back to the button.

```
$('#tags a').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var send = $(this).attr('href');
$.ajax({
    url:'getitemsfortag.php',
    data:{tag:send},
    type:'GET',
    dataType:'html',
    success:function(data){
        $('#items').empty().append(data); //data contains list of buttons
    },
    error:function(xhr, status){
        alert("Problem");
    }
});

});

$("input[type='button']").live('click',function(){
var selected = $(this).attr("id");
var val = prompt("Enter new value",0);
$this = $(this);
$.ajax({
    url:'updateCostItems.php',
    data:{toupdate:selected, updatewith:val},
    type:'GET',
    dataType:'json',
    success:function(json){
        $this.val(json.update);
    },
    error:function(xhr, status){
        alert("Problem");
    }
    });
});
});
```

Any suggestion on how to get the changed value to be written back to the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this.html(json.update);
```

instead of

```
$(this).val(json.update);
```

Comment: What happens when you do that?

Comment: If you add an alert in the success function does it display anything or is it not getting there?

Comment: @devmatt: the `update` variable is getting set with desired value but the button value is not changing..

Comment: Ok, but i first want to determine if the success callback is getting called.

Comment: @devmatt: the `alert(json.update)` inside `success` gives me the value so the success callback is getting called right?

Comment: Yes, what does firebug output when you do a `console.log($this);` in the success function?

Comment: @devmatt: [input#items78 45]  that's #item for button id and 45 for OLD button value

Comment: Please try `$this.val(json.update);` and `$this.attr('value', json.update);`